# Повторение нажатий клавиш python

Tags: python, клавиатура

Мне надо сделать программу, которая будет записывать кнопки, нажатые человеком, а потом их воспроизводить. Но нужно также учитывать задержку между нажатием и отпусканием клавиши. Идея такова: есть список с кнопками, в формате `[[кнопка, задержка]]`. Программа читает первый элемент, нажимает соответствующую кнопку и отпускает через время во втором элементе.
Пробовал сделать через keyboard, но нормальных функций не нашёл. Как можно это сделать и есть ли библиотеки, которые легко отслеживают отпускание кнопки?

Comment: У [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) есть функции `recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')` и `keyboard.play(recorded)`